# How can an object refer to itself in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can i fix this so it prints `this should show`? I'm building an app where I need `obj: myObj` or even `obj: 'myObj'` to refer to itself.

Lines 1-3 are only there to demonstrate the error.

```js
let myObj = {
  text: 'this shouldn\'t show'
};

myObj = {
  text: 'this should show',
  obj: myObj
}

function show(object) {
  document.write(object.text);
}

show(myObj.obj);
```

Comment: `myObj.obj = myObj;`?

Comment: You're overwriting `myObj` with a new object, referencing the old one. `let myObj = { text: 'this should show' }; myObj.obj = myObj;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with an object pointing to itself, which is completely achievable via `object.property = object`. You have two different objects here, being assigned in turn to the same variable. At the point in time when your second object literal is created with `obj: myObj`, `myObj` (the variable) still contains the *first* object you created.

If you want the object to point to itself, simply add a property with the correct value:

```
myObj = {
  text: 'this should show'
}

myObj.obj = myObj;
```

Answer (score 0):

`show(myObj.obj);` should be `show(myObj);`

Answer (score 0):

1. let myObj = {
2. text: 'this shouldn\'t show'
3. };

The code snipped above creates a myObj variable with a "text" property.

```
4. myObj = {
5.  text: 'this should show',
6.  obj: myObj
7. }
```

The code above overrides the variable "myObj" with new object structure with "text" property and "obj" property which is initialized to the object created in code lines 1-3 in which the text property is intialized to value 'this shouldn\'t show'

If you change the code to

```
let myObj = {
  text: 'this shouldn\'t show'
};

//Override the objects text property
myObj.text = 'this should show';
//create a property obj and make it refer to the same object.
myObj.obj = myObj;

function show(object) {
  document.write(object.text);
}

show(myObj.obj);
```

it should work

Answer (score -1):

```
let myObj = {
  text: 'this shouldn\'t show'
};

myObj = {
  text: 'this should show',
}
myObj.obj = myObj;

function show(object) {
  console.log(object.text);
}

show(myObj.obj);
```

This should work